# My Ajax form submit is not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My form is not working. It's doing success on even if the query didn't execute like I want username to be unique so I want to trigger an error when username is not unique and then if success I want then to redirect to a page namely as "clients.php" so here is my code for form please as :

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_client').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
          url:'add_client_query.php',
          data:$(this).serialize(),
          type:'POST',
          success:function(data, textStatus) {
            console.log(data);     
            window.location.href = "clients.php";    // Show Success Message
          },
          error:function(data) {
            $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);    // Show Error Message
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();    // To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"
    });
});
</script>
```

Here Is HTML Form Code :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error" style="display:none;">One Account Is Already Exist There With The Username.Please Try With Unqiue Username.</div>
<form role="form" action="add_client_query.php" method="post" id="add_client">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username :</label>
    <input name="username" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input name="password" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Assign Form</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="formlink">
      <?php    // $resultset now holds all rows from the first query.
      foreach ($resultset as $result) {  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $result['form_name']; ?>"><?php echo ucwords($result['form_name']); ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Do You Want To Assign Invoice To The Client?</label></br>
    <label><input type="radio" id="yes" name="invoice_choice[]" id="optionsRadios1" value="Yes"> Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" id="no" name="invoice_choice[]" id="optionsRadios1" value="No"> No</label>
  </div>
  <div class="invoice_price" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group" >
      <label>Invoice Price :</label>
      <input name="invoice_price"  class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div><!-- end div invoice_price -->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
</form>
```

and here is PHP Code for query:

```
<?php
include('../config/config.php');
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['admin']) { 
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $formlink = $_POST['formlink'];
        $invoice_choice = $_POST['invoice_choice'];
        foreach ($invoice_choice as $invoice_choice) 
        { }
        if ($invoice_choice=="Yes") {
            $invoice_price = $_POST['invoice_price'];
            $invoice_status = "Pending";
        } elseif ($invoice_choice=="No") {
            $invoice_price = "0";
            $invoice_status = "Not Assigned";
        }
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO clientlog  (Username,Password,formlink,invoice_price,invoice_status)
        VALUES ('$username','$password','$formlink','$invoice_price','$invoice_status');") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
} else {
    header('Location:index.php');
} 
?>
```

so it will be so kindful if you people please let me know where I am doing anything wrong please.

Comment: This code is very bad and full of bad practices

Comment: really I am a beginner to developemnt..!

Comment: any help would be great..! please to findout what is really I am doing wrong..

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't even read what you wrote

Comment: It's simple all others things are working fine for now ajax is not working it do success even if query is not executed..! rather it should trigger that error message..!

Comment: You don't need to do a `foreach` for your radio buttons, since they bear the same name group and it's only a Yes or No. You'd need to remove the loop and the brackets for `name="invoice_choice[]"` and remove both `id="optionsRadios1"` - Had they'd been checkboxes, that would be a different story.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Thanks for suggestion...I have done so as you said..! but really now main issue is in ajax so more details on that will be great..!

Comment: You're welcome. You also have a \ in `"INSERT INTO clientlog  \(Username,Password` remove it.

Comment: `die($message)` does not set an HTTP error code on its own. Without an error code, the ajax request assumes success.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Sorry for `\` mistakenly it got into the code while indenting the code in question it doesn't really exist in actual code..!

Comment: You misunderstand what the `success` handler does: That part gets executed when your php scripts terminates successfully / without errors, **regardless of the output**. So if `$_SESSION['admin']` evaluates to `false`, you will go to your `success` handler in javascript. You should check in that `success` handler what the output of your script is. Also, you can't do any php redirects in an ajax call and you should not do them in js when you are debugging.

Comment: @jeroen : but the `$_SESSION['admin']` is working fine..as I am already in session it's in admin panel so it can't be false it evaluates as true.! and hence the ajax is not working fine..!

Comment: That was just an example to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @jeroen : it's really confusing,can you be more specific to the issue that what is really going wrong there please..! as the rest is working fine..!

Comment: on checking in firebug it output as _(an empty string)_ on success handler..! changed the redirect to alert for debugging please..

Comment: @BrianS : so how to set an HTTP Error code when the query fails and then will ajax work fine?

Comment: You can get or set the HTTP response code with `http_response_code` or set it with `header`.

Comment: @BrianS : Thanks for your answer it really worked.post this as an answer and I will select it to end my question that it is solved..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the "do or `die()`" construction in your PHP code, which is the primary source of confusion over the ajax `success` and `error` functions. (Note that it isn't a great practice, you might want to check out the codereview.SE to improve your application.)

From the PHP manual:

> This language construct is equivalent to exit().

While you can set `$status` as a parameter for `exit` or `die`, this is simply a code to tell how the PHP code exited, not the HTTP response code (in fact, the exit status must be in the range [0,254], so you *can't* get most of the HTTP response codes)

The ajax `error` function will run if the ajax call gets an HTTP response code indicating an error. However, simply calling `die()` will return status code 200 (which indicates success). Your PHP script was successfully called, even if it might have exited with a nonzero status.

In order to change the HTTP response code, you have two options:

1. Use the `http_response_code` function, which can get or set the response code.
2. Use the `header` function to send the response code manually.